# Show records contain multiple key words using OR or if elif (filter rows)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I am trying to show the rows that contain set of key words.

The table look like this

```
Col0     col1      col2     col3
1         LD        AN       CC
2         AB      LD SS      BB
1         AA      LD AD      CC
3         LD        AC       NN
2         FF        UH       BB
```

What I want is to filter this table where the row contain the tow strings (LD and AB) OR (LD and AD) OR (AC)

So I get this result

```
Col0     col1      col2     col3
2         AB      LD SS      BB
1         AA      LD AD      CC
3         LD        AC       NN
```

I tried

```
count = df.groupby(['Col0','Col3'])['Col3'].transform('size')
s = df['Col1'] + ' ---- ' + df['Col2'] 

#The condition function 
df = df[count.isin([1,2]) (s.str.contains('LD') & s.str.contains('AB')) | (s.str.contains('LD') & s.str.contains('AD')) | (s.str.contains('LD') & s.str.contains('AC'))]
```

This obviously didn't work , so I tried using the if function:

```
if s.str.contains('L/D') & s.str.contains('AB'):
   df = df[count.eq(2)]
elif s.str.contains('L/D') & s.str.contains('AD'):
    df = df[count.eq(2)]
elif s.str.contains('L/D') & s.str.contains('AC'):
    df = df[count.eq(2)]
```

and using this

```
if 'L/D' & 'AB' in s:
    df = df[count.eq(2)]
elif 'L/D' & 'AD' in s:
    df = df[count.eq(2)]
elif 'L/D' & 'AC' in s:
    df = df[count.eq(2)]
```

They didn't work

So can someone help with what I made wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
df = df[count.isin([1,2]) (s.str.contains('LD') & s.str.contains('AB'))
        | (s.str.contains('LD') & s.str.contains('AD'))
        | (s.str.contains('LD') & s.str.contains('AC'))]
```

contains a syntax error because of `count`. Remove it and you get the expected result:

```
df = df[(s.str.contains('LD') & s.str.contains('AB'))
        | (s.str.contains('LD') & s.str.contains('AD'))
        | (s.str.contains('LD') & s.str.contains('AC'))]
```

giving:

```
   Col0 Col1   Col2 Col3
1     2   AB  LD SS   BB
2     1   AA  LD AD   CC
3     3   LD     AC   NN
```